# Compactness of sets in metric spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm reading Kolmogorov's functional analysis book and I have a question concerning the definition it gives for a compact subset of a metric space (page 51, 1st volume for those interested to check it out).

*A set M in the metric space R is said to be compact if every sequence of elements in M contains a subsequence which converges **to a point x in R**.*

I'm confused,shouldn't the subsequence converge **to a point x in the set M**? In the real numbers a compact set is a bounded and closed one, but the definition above (seems to me) allows the open interval (a,b) to be compact, since every sequence in (a,b) is bounded and therefore contains a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; $x$ should be required to be in $M$.  This is presumably a typo.